# Sending array as querystring parameter in senchatouch2

Tags: arrays, post, methods, sencha-touch-2, query-string

How to send Arrays as querystring parameters in Ajax request using POST methos to access a third party webservice..

Kindly provide sample code ..

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? some code or research attempt?

Comment: This community will assist you with problems you may face in creating your code/project, but we will not write your code for you. Please post any code you may already have.

Comment: My code is:
In Ajax Request,
params:{
Title:'["Miss","Master","Miss","Master"]',
FirstName:'["Annie","Alb","Achu","Dev"]',
LastName:'["Rose","Peter","Diana","Albert"]',
DOB:'["2013/06/12","2013/06/12","2013/06/12","2013/06/12"]',
PassangerCode:'["ADT","CHD","CHD","INF"]',
}
Is this correct way of sending array as querystring parameters..
Kindly provide sample code

Comment: Is sending array as querystring parameter possible in senchatouch2..If possible kindly provide sample code as i am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While v use POST method to send parameters in SenchaTouch2 use **jsonData** instead of params in Ajax Request like,

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url:'',
method:'POST',
disableCaching:false,
headers: {
          'Accept':'application/json',
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
         },
**jsonData**: {
           FirstName:fname  //{"FirstName":["Sam","paul"]}
              },
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I usually do it

```
...
params: {
  array: Ext.encode(['1', '2', '3'])
},
...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried Ext.encode..Now my array is passing as querystring value Thanks a lot..but still i cant access webservice

Comment: What web service are you trying to access? It'd be great to know a bit more on what's on the other side of your app.

Comment: I want to STORE a BULK of data into database through webservice(Storing Passenger Details in database)..since  through GET method we can send only limit of querystring values m using POST and sending BULK of data as Array values through querystring

Comment: While Accessing webservice,I faced this Error....The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Psngr'. Encountered unexpected character 'F'.'. See server logs for more details.